# anylogic - Priority task for resourcepool

Tags: java, anylogic

Priority task for resourcepool

Hi, I need help with anylogic. I would like to set a priority function on a specific activity for the resource pool operators. the resourcepool is allocated to both task 1 and task 2. I would like priority to be given to task 2. so if there are agents ready to be worked on in both tasks, task 2 is done first.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n9CK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help